# php array_filter by date

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

New to PHP so not sure if this is the best way. Basically I have a record-set with results, now I could do 3 or 4 queries & return the results as I need them, but I thought it would be more efficient to have one query and filter the results in an array as I need them.

I get the results into an array, now I want to display the results by day week and month so it makes sense to me to loop the array 3 times for day, week and month rather than 3 calls to the database.

First question is this the best way in PHP???

Second is I cant work out how to use the array_filter($array_name, DATE?) I can't get the date part working.

The array/recordset could be:

name, target, date

and I want to show the results of this by day, week & month.

So I got:

```
    array_filter($staff_tagret_results,"evaldate");
```

And a function:

```
    function evaldate($x) {
    if($staff_tagret_results == DAY/WEEK/MONTH){
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I can't find out how to target the date filed of the array and compare against today?

Thanks for any advice.

ARRAY CONTENTS:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 11[0] => 11[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 115[2] => 115
    ) [1] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 4[0] => 4[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 115[2] => 115
    ) [2] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 9[0] => 9[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 115[2] => 115
    ) [3] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 11[0] => 11[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 115[2] => 115
    ) [4] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 4[0] => 4[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 115[2] => 115
    ) [5] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 9[0] => 9[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 115[2] => 115
    ) [6] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 11[0] => 11[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 240[2] => 240
    ) [7] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 4[0] => 4[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 240[2] => 240
    ) [8] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 9[0] => 9[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 240[2] => 240
    ) [9] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 4[0] => 4[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 180[2] => 180
    ) [10] => Array(
        [staff_id] => 9[0] => 9[work_date] => 2014 - 02 - 12[1] => 2014 - 02 - 12[target_set] => 180[2] => 180
    )
)
```

Comment: Show content of original array

Comment: Done, sorry I didn't bother as it's just the date field I wanted to filter.

Comment: Make your code readable

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. I'm not asking you to code anything I am asking for advice. Although I have added code samples and the array as requested. All I wanted to know was if this is the best way and if it is how do you target an array element to filter? mainly the date.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment due to not having enough reputation:

If you look at your original post you see what what hindmost meant by "Make your code readable"

Back to your question:

I am confused why you have every value in your arrays 2 x:

```
Array ( 
       [staff_id] => 11 [0] => 11
       [work_date] => 2014-02-12 [1] => 2014-02-12
       [target_set] => 115 [2] => 115 )
```

If I do a simple select query I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [staff_id] => 4
            [work_date] => 2014-02-18
            [target_set] => 115
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [staff_id] => 9
            [work_date] => 2014-02-20
            [target_set] => 115
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [staff_id] => 11
            [work_date] => 2014-02-20
            [target_set] => 115
        )

)
```

If you want to sort your Array:

```
foreach ($aArray as $key => $row) {
    $date[$key]    = $row['work_date'];
 }

 array_multisort($date, SORT_DESC, $aArray);
```

This will get you:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [staff_id] => 9
            [work_date] => 2014-02-20
            [target_set] => 115
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [staff_id] => 11
            [work_date] => 2014-02-20
            [target_set] => 115
       )

    [2] => Array
       (
            [staff_id] => 4
            [work_date] => 2014-02-18
            [target_set] => 115
       )

)
```

This ist how I would do it. There may be an easier way :-)

Mark

EDIT: Changed sort direction, so that a change in the array is visible

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I want to filter the array not sort it.

Comment: okay. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Have you tried array_filter (http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php)

You also can do it manually:

`foreach($aArray as $value)
{ 
 if ($value['work_date'] == date("Y-m-d")
 {
 $filtered[] = $value;
 }
}`